# GNOME top panel discolored when running fglrx

Tags: graphics, gnome, fglrx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ati incompatible with Gnome-shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62808/ati-incompatible-with-gnome-shell)

I installed Gnome-Shell on Ubuntu 11.10 and the top bar has a strange glitch:

[image]

I also installed ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics drivers but the "post-release updates" fails to install.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/62808/18612

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the ATI/AMD drivers not being compatible. Its a problem on their end, and there isn't much that can be done about it as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It's "fixed" in the newest fglrx from the ATI homepage. Fixed meaning, that the colors are ok, but the shell flickers and is still unusable.