# Gnome Shell Glitched Top Bar Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, ati, gnome, fglrx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with gnome3-shell (top taskbar)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar)

I am having a similar problem with gnome shell as this question:
[Gnome-shell does not display top toolbar panel using a Mobility Radeon 5650](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62808/ati-incompatible-with-gnome-shell)

However mine is slightly stranger. Unfortunately I can't take a screenshot (If I do all you can see is the background), but for me the background of the top bar is the File Edit View etc menu from unity. The buttons don't actually work and are not clickable. Fonts, text etc looks the same as in the question mentioned above. This is really frustrating as I really want to use gnome shell. It appears the problem is with fgrlx, but I hope that by now there is a fix.

Also please not that the Activities screen (With the applications and the search, etc) is absolutely fine. Context menus and tooltips are glitched and skewed all around the system however.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the Global Menu in Unity. You can remove it by uninstalling the appmenu package, but this will likely cause problems if you still use Unity as well.

Alternatively you could disable Nautilus from managing your desktop, but then your desktop would just be a plain wallpaper.