# Gnome-shell, how to fix it?

Tags: ati, graphics, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ati incompatible with Gnome-shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62808/ati-incompatible-with-gnome-shell)

my gnome-shell display screen  is tilted/ skewed, how do I fix it? sometimes the screen flashes, how do I fix it? I've installed the ATI Catalyst 11.9

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/62808/18612

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `fglrx` drivers, at the moment (`fglrx 11.9`) do not work with GNOME Shell.

You need to access a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) or boot in to recovery mode (press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right before Ubuntu is supposed to load and keep it pressed until the Grub menu comes up).

Login and run:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score -3):

Follow this guide: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To avoid potential problems with linkrot, can you please edit the steps from the guide you have linked to back into your answer? As it stands now, your answer is little more than a link to an external site, which makes it [subject to deletion](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion). Thanks!