# GNOME Shell flickering with ATI proprietary drivers

Tags: 11.10, ati, gnome, proprietary, flicker

Works fine with opensource drivers, but with catalyst flickers everytime you press on activities or the lower right bar.

I have 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon HD 3600 Series

Running fresh ubuntu 11.10 and catalyst 11.10 from ati.com website.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I want to use the proprietary drivers I know that opensource ones work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/62808/ati-incompatible-with-gnome-shell

Comment: Not a duplicate the person there has problem with fonts and the panel, mine is flickering ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ATI graphics card, with gnome shell, screen flickers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78364/ati-graphics-card-with-gnome-shell-screen-flickers)

Comment: Working perfect with AMD Driver 12.1. :)

Comment: Duplicate question - [ATI graphics card, with gnome shell, screen flickers][1] (partially solved)


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78364/ati-graphics-card-with-gnome-shell-screen-flickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This steps worked for me and what you probabably should do is upgrade you ATI drivers. They have solved a lot of those issues you're facing on.

**http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-1112-linux.html**

**For smooth installation, it is recommended to uninstall currently availabe Catalyst driver. To do this, use these commands from the terminal:**

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

**To install the AMD Catalyst 11.12 Linux driver now on Ubuntu 11.10 (32-bit & 64-bit) or any older version, run this sequence of commands:**

```
cd ~/;
mkdir catalyst11.12; 
cd catalyst11.12/

wget -O ati-driver-installer-11-12.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run
```

**If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything**

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

After that you can start installing the new ati driver:

```
chmod +x ati-driver-installer-11-12.run 

sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-12.run
```

**Make now an update for the X.org file with this command:**

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f

sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall proprietary drivers.

I did it last week and latest version of open source drivers works perfectly.

---

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

---

Comment: I know that opensource one works, I need proprietary ones.

Comment: If the open source driver works, but the proprietary one does not, I highly suggest you file a bug report with ATI. Support for closed source drivers is fairly minimal and does not typically extend beyond installation and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove Screenlets if you have ones, it helped for me (Ubuntu 11.10, AMD Proprietary Drivers 11.10).

Comment: Don't have any.

Answer (score -3):

To solve this (with propietary drivers) install compiz manager, then go to OpenGL and make sure all the options are unchecked. Restart and you are good to go (:

Comment: As I stated I'm using gnome-shell not Unity. Gnome-shell doesn't use compiz.

Comment: oh, that's a problem, sorry I couldn't help you ;D