# Gnome Shell and ATI driver

Tags: gnome, ati, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ATI graphics card, with gnome shell, screen flickers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78364/ati-graphics-card-with-gnome-shell-screen-flickers)

I've updated my open source ATI driver to the closed source version. Consequently my Gnome Shell stopped working as well as it used to work. It started to flash weirdly.

I recorded short video to show it:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpEwn7Fi8Qw

Before the driver update, the Gnome Shell worked fine. With new driver the Unity works fine.

I still prefer Shell (when it still worked correctly), so is there something I can do to fix this issue.

Comment: Where did you install the driver from? What version?

Comment: I have asked the same question a while back. Here was the [answere](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78364/ati-graphics-card-with-gnome-shell-screen-flickers). Problem still not solved, but it's better. Anyway, I use Unity now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I managed to make it better in the CCC, but it still isn't as good as with open source driver.

Comment: I downloaded it from ATI's website