# Ubuntu will not leave 2d mode

Tags: 12.04, drivers, unity, amd-graphics, unity-2d

I am running 12.04 LTS, have received all of the updates, and cannot switch back to 3d mode. After restarting and notifying the GUI that I would like to start in Ubuntu (3d) mode, it goes to 2d mode anyway.

The only recent changes I've performed are installing 1) updates and 2) dropbox. I've tried disabling dropbox without success, so I doubt that it is the culprit. I've tried various other re-installs for the drivers.

As a note, the GUI for additional drivers is blank (and suspiciously so), whereas previously I had an ATI driver. An image of the blank GUI is below, because I recall there were tabs and so forth in it, but none are visible:

[image: intended image 2]

I've reinstalled the FLGX drivers and similar drivers and followed these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252018/your-ubuntu-12-04-is-running-in-2d-mode-many-features-will-not-be-available-ub).

No success.  Are there any other suggestions?

Note, my graphics driver is Integrated ATI Radeon™ HD 4250 GPU as part of an Asus  M4A88T-M

Note:

```
 /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
        X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
        Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
        Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
        Serial number of failed request:  22
        Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Comment: Does your gpu support 3d acceleration? Maybe you have to enable that.

Comment: I don't know. How would I establish something like that?

I have inquired and found that:
'glxinfo | grep direct' returns the same error as above, which is alarming.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. Apparently one of the drivers was failing in this set of [commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

Notably, step 6, "Generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING!", was failing. After following everything up until step six, I went [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122354/aticonfig-no-supported-adapters-detected-error-when-installing-ati-radeon-hd) and followed the answer by Rostyk, then rebooted.

Unity 3d now works again.

Thank you!